# How can I upgrade the Web Matrix Umbraco template to the latest version of Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, webmatrix

Using the MS Web Platform Installer, I installed WebMatrix and the Umbraco template. Umbraco just released a new version (5.0.1) and I'd like to make that the new template that WebMatrix uses. I'm having a little trouble figuring out where those files are stored/accessed.

In other words, when I launch WebMatric, and select to create a new Umbraco project, I want it to create a 5.0.1 Umbraco project.

I have the 5.0.1 files from CodePlex - it is my assumption that I can copy those somewhere and make it work. I'm just not sure where that is, or if there is anything special I should know about that.

Comment: What version of Umbraco did you pull down from Web PI?

Comment: I created an Umbraco website, and this is in the Web.config. I assume this is the version?     <add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="4.7.1.1" />

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a brand new Umbraco 5 site running under WebMatrix, the easiest way is to use [Web PI](http://www.microsoft.com/web/umbraco).

However, if you downloaded one of the *WebDeploy Packages* from [CodePlex](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases) and want to add it as a WebMatrix template under *WebMatrix > Quick Start > Site From Template*, you should be able to derive what you need to do from [this tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/169/Creating-A-Custom-Template-For-WebMatrix) on creating custom WebMatrix templates.

You may also want to reference the Umbraco documentation on [installing Umbraco manually.](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco5Docs/blob/5.0.1/Documentation/Getting-Started/Installing-Umbraco-Manually.md)